# How to change an image onclick while li on current status using pure CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to change an image to some other image when i click on the object. the code is stacked in the following order:

HTML :

```
<div class="games-platform-item pt-item">
                    <ul class="games-sub-menu clearfix"> 

                            <li class="tab1 current">
                            <img src="../images/abc11.jpg"/ class="topimgG1" ">
                            <span>编辑精选</span>
                            </li>

                        <li class="tab2">
                        <img src="../images/abc2.jpg"/ class="topimgG2" ">
                        <span>老虎机</span>
                        </li> 

                        <li class="tab3">
                        <img src="../images/abc3.jpg"/ class="topimgG3" ">
                        <span>桌面游戏</span>
                        </li>

                        <li class="tab4">
                        <img src="../images/abc4.jpg"/ class="topimgG4" ">
                        <span>累计大奖</span>
                        </li>

                        <li class="tab5">
                        <img src="../images/abc5.jpg"/ class="topimgG5" ">
                        <span>小游戏</span>
                        </li>    

                        <li class="tab6">
                        <img src="../images/abc6.jpg"/ class="topimgG6" ">  
                        <span>视频扑克</span>
                        </li>    

                        <li class="tab7">
                        <img src="../images/abc7.jpg"/ class="topimgG7" ">
                        <span>所有游戏</span>
                        </li>     

                        <li class="tab8 games-pt-search" style="display:none;"><span>搜索结果</span></li>
                    </ul>
```

What i wish to do is :

i want to change the image to a colored version of the image when it onclick, ie, some other image. Now, I know i can use jquery/JS to accomplish it. But i dont want a huge amount of JS code to accomplish something so simple.
Can it be done using something simpler? Like .current in CSS

I cannot seem to think of it.

CSS :

Comment: Not with the markup you have and that's not really how CSS works **but** I do have a somewhat hacky solution using background images, labels and hidden checkboxes if you are interested.

Comment: @JonP Hi JonP , Please advise on this issue .. thanks you

Comment: Pure CSS with [tag:jquery] tag? Really??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the basic idea. It can be improved immensly by using CSS sprites. Using sprites will also iliminate the delay in loding the on click image. For an introduction to CSS Sprites see: https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

I haven't used sprites here as they are hard to emulate usind palceholdit, which I have used for the image.

On to the code. I will outline what it does and key features after.

```css
/*Hide the Radio Button*/
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio] {
  display: none
}

/*Set a box for the label, this is what is clicked on*/
.games-sub-menu label {
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
}

/*Set Images...this would work better with sprites*/
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG1 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/FF0000/FFFFFF/?text=Image1");
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG1 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/?text=Image1");
}
.games-sub-menu label.topimgG2 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/00FF00/FFFFFF/?text=Image2");
}
.games-sub-menu input[type=radio]:checked + label.topimgG2 {
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/150x100/?text=Image2");
}
```

```html
<div class="games-platform-item pt-item">
  <ul class="games-sub-menu clearfix">
    <li class="tab1 current">
      <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg1">
      <label class="topimgG1" for="rdoImg1"></label>
      <span>编辑精选</span>
    </li>
    <li class="tab2 current">
      <input type="radio" name="imgSwap" id="rdoImg2">
      <label class="topimgG2" for="rdoImg2"></label>
      <span>编辑精选</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Basically what is going on here is the hidden radio button is maintaining the state of the image. From there we use the `checked` CSS selector in conjuntion with the adjacent sibling selector `+` to chanage the background image of the label. **Important Note** the check box must come immediately before the label. You could use the general sibling selector, but the check box must still come before the label.

You could also replace `radio` with checkbox if the choices aren't mutually exclusive.

You could also achive a similar result using links to an id on the page, and utilize the `:target` selector. But this would introduce a page jump.

Some of my answers that use similar concepts:

- [How to edit this nav to make it a click nav instead of a hover nav?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30991453/how-to-edit-this-nav-to-make-it-a-click-nav-instead-of-a-hover-nav/30992445#30992445)
- [All css accordion divs open by default (no jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30090345/all-css-accordion-divs-open-by-default-no-jquery/30092724#30092724)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30115605/4665

Comment: Hi Jon , its working perfectly thanks very much for the help . you are genius :D

Answer (score 0):

Simple with Jquery.

Example:

```
$(function() {
 $('.topimgG1').click(function(){
   // First set all to default image
   resetAll();
   // Then set the clicked image to another image.
   $(".topimgG1").attr('src',"../img/<another image>");
   return false;
 });
});

function resetAll()
{
 var arrofIDS= ["topimgG1", "topimgG2", "topimgG3"];

 for (i = 0; i < arrofIDS.length; i++) { 
     $("."+arrofIDS[i]).attr('src',"../img/<default img>");
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi ， how to remove the color image on topimgG1 and set it to default color if im clicking other image

Comment: Note that this will have to load the new image on the click, so there mybe a slight delay in loading the image.

Comment: i have updated the answer; now upon clicking on an image, all the others will be set to default

Comment: @xestes Hi , sorry im new on this jquery function , may i know how to insert multiple img default in for (i = 0; i < arrofIDS.length; i++) { 
     $("."+arrofIDS[i]).attr('src',"../img/<default img>");
  }

Comment: @MorganNg Just add all the IDs into the arrofIDS array. e.g. var arrofIDS= ["topimgG1", "topimgG2", "topimgG3", "id4", "id5", "id6",  etc...]; ... this will set all of those elements to default image

Comment: @xestes Hi , i think this method not working very well as the image i set it on html side not in css if i put all element of id class in into de array . it will set all the image into unknown image which blank image

Answer (score 0):

You can store the alternative source like this:

```
<li class="tab2">
    <img data-alt-src="path/to/alt/img" src="../images/abc2.jpg"/ class="topimgG2" ">
    <span>老虎机</span>
</li>
```

And then write a script like this:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $('.topimgG').click(function(){
            var src = $(this).attr("src");
            var altSrc = $(this).attr("data-alt-src");
            $(this).attr("src", altsrc);
       });
    });
</script>
```

The other solutions might or might not add much javascript code, but it will definetly serve your purpose.

Comment: Hi , on this <img data-alt-src="path/to/alt/img" is to change the alternative image?

Comment: In the data-alt-src attribute you can store the alternative image URL

Comment: Give your images the same class topimgG

Answer (score 0):

```
.class:active{background: url(iamge.jpg);
 }
```

you can use this active for changing your image temporary on onclick